# Can capistrano be used for non web applications

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I want to deploy my non web application to server. Wheni was going thru this site 'http://theme.fm/2011/08/tutorial-deploying-wordpress-with-capistrano-2082/' the first line says capitrano is used to deploy web applications. I am confused should i proceed with capistrano or not..

Comment: It is normally used to deploy web applications. But it can be used to deploy anything.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sergio...

Answer (score 1):

Capistrano is a remote orchestration library, basically it is a nice API for running commands over ssh on a remote server.

As an example, it can be used to run provisioning/setup scripts on a remote server. See the [Rubygems AWS](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-aws) repository for an example of this.